# generate rows with ffill based on specific condition - pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df as shown below

```
Date                   B_best         B_worst     W_best            W_worst
2020-08-11             3              1           10                7
2020-08-12             3              1           10                7
2020-08-13             3              1           10                7
2020-08-14             3              1           10                7
2020-08-15             6              1           10                7
2020-08-16             6              2           10                11
2020-08-17             6              2           5                 11
2020-08-18             6              2           5                 11
2020-08-19             9              2           5                 11
2020-08-20             9              2           4                 11
2020-08-21             9              2           4                 11   
2020-08-22             5              3           7                 13         
2020-08-23             10             6           8                 16 
2020-08-24             9              2           4                 11
```

Above df has a column called `Date` from the above I would like to have a function whose input will be above df and a date value

```
df1 = generate_data(df, datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 20, 0))
```

where datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 20, 0) means 2020-09-02

Expected Output

df1:

```
Date                   B_best         B_worst     W_best            W_worst
2020-08-11             3              1           10                7
2020-08-12             3              1           10                7
2020-08-13             3              1           10                7
2020-08-14             3              1           10                7
2020-08-15             6              1           10                7
2020-08-16             6              2           10                11
2020-08-17             6              2           5                 11
2020-08-18             6              2           5                 11
2020-08-19             9              2           5                 11
2020-08-20             9              2           4                 11
2020-08-21             9              2           4                 11   
2020-08-22             5              3           7                 13         
2020-08-23             10             6           8                 16 
2020-08-24             9              2           4                 11
2020-08-25             9              2           4                 11
2020-08-26             9              2           4                 11
2020-08-27             9              2           4                 11
2020-08-28             9              2           4                 11
2020-08-29             9              2           4                 11
2020-08-30             9              2           4                 11
2020-08-31             9              2           4                 11
2020-09-01             9              2           4                 11
2020-09-02             9              2           4                 11
```

It has generated data till 2020-09-02 with the same value final row of the available df.

Note:

If input date is greater than maximum date then return df1, else return df

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the Dates are continuous and the input date will always be greater than the minimum Date available in the dataframe,  You can create a date_range series using the `min` from the existing `Date` column, then `right` merge followed by ffill:

```
def generate_data(a,b):
    idx = pd.date_range(a['Date'].min(),b)
    return a.merge(pd.Series(idx,name='Date'),how='right').ffill().astype(a.dtypes)
print(generate_data(df, datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 20, 0)))
```

EDIT1:
to adjust and return the original df if input date is less than minimum date, you can edit the function:

```
def generate_data(a,b):
    idx = pd.date_range(a['Date'].min(),b)
    out = a.merge(pd.Series(idx,name='Date'),how='right').ffill().astype(a.dtypes)
    return a if b<a['Date'].min() else out
```

EDIT2:

If input date is greater than maximum date, then return df1, else return df.

```
def generate_data(df, b):
    if df['Date'].max() <  b:
        idx = pd.date_range(df['Date'].min(),b)
        return df.merge(pd.Series(idx,name='Date'),how='right').ffill().astype(df.dtypes)
    else:
        return df
```

---

```
         Date  B_best  B_worst  W_best  W_worst
0  2020-08-11       3        1      10        7
1  2020-08-12       3        1      10        7
2  2020-08-13       3        1      10        7
3  2020-08-14       3        1      10        7
4  2020-08-15       6        1      10        7
5  2020-08-16       6        2      10       11
6  2020-08-17       6        2       5       11
7  2020-08-18       6        2       5       11
8  2020-08-19       9        2       5       11
9  2020-08-20       9        2       4       11
10 2020-08-21       9        2       4       11
11 2020-08-22       5        3       7       13
12 2020-08-23      10        6       8       16
13 2020-08-24       9        2       4       11
14 2020-08-25       9        2       4       11
15 2020-08-26       9        2       4       11
16 2020-08-27       9        2       4       11
17 2020-08-28       9        2       4       11
18 2020-08-29       9        2       4       11
19 2020-08-30       9        2       4       11
20 2020-08-31       9        2       4       11
21 2020-09-01       9        2       4       11
22 2020-09-02       9        2       4       11
```

Comment: if input date is less than minimum date return df as it is. Code should not break.

Comment: @Danish it wouldnt break but would return an empty dataframe, tested with `generate_data(df, datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 2, 20, 0))`

Comment: Can we make it return the initial df in that case

Comment: @Danish I would like you to try that :) (*thats a conditional check*)  if you face issue let me know I will help you.!!

Comment: I tried this 

def generate_data(a,b):
    if a['Date'].max() <  b:
        idx = pd.date_range(a['Date'].min(),b)
        return a.merge(pd.Series(idx,name='Date'),how='right').ffill().astype(a.dtypes)
    else:
        return a

Comment: If input date is greater than maximum date then return out, else return a.. That is the expected output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220376/discussion-between-danish-and-anky).